# Similar library of Choco in C#

Tags: java, c#, constraints, choco

Is there any similar library in C# for [Choco](http://www.emn.fr/z-info/choco-solver/) (Contraint Programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the technology in question, but there is the Microsoft Solver Foundation which appears to do Constraint Programming

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/hh145003.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff826354(v=vs.93).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This site doesn't list any http://www.constraintsolving.com/solvers, so there may be no good ones.

You can use a C or C++ one by linking it into a C++/CLI managed/unmanaged assembly and wrapping it in C++/CLI managed classes.  Then you'd be able to call from C#.

Comment: The only VB.NET library is no longer in development since 2004

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for open source alternatives in C#, you should definitely try [Google or-tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/).